# run a test case on a method that returns a promise with jasmine

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm writing a test case for a function that returns a promise.

```
newItem: any;

  public getNewItem() {
    this.storage.get('newItem').then((response) => {
        if (response) {
           this.newItem = response
        } else {
            this.doReset();
        }

  }
```

When i run the test all doReset get called the reason being newItem is not being assigned. How do i set new item so doReset doesn't run.

This is the spec file:

```
describe('ItemService', () => {
  let service: ItemService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientModule,RouterTestingModule, IonicStorageModule.forRoot()],
      providers: [
        {provide: AlertService}
        ],
    });
    service = TestBed.inject(ItemService);
  });

  it('should be current item', () => {
    service.newItem = {name: 'Daniel', photos: ['image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg']}
    spyOn(service,'getCurrentItem').and.callThrough();
  });


});
```

Answer (score 0):

There exist different ways to write [asynchronous tests](https://jasmine.github.io/tutorials/async) with `Jasmine`. In your case, the easiest way would be to use `async`/`await` as follows:

```
it('should be current item', async () => {

  // given
  const newItem = {name: 'Daniel', photos: ['image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg']};
  service.newItem = newItem;

  // when
  const item = await service.getNewItem();

  // then
  expect(item).toBe(newItem);
});
```